# Java's Format specifier printing the output repeatedly

Tags: java, format

I have written a Java program to print the numbers from 1 to 10, with spaced formatting. Using `java.util.Formatter`, I do not get the expected output. Why?

The expected output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class CountTo10 {
    static void formatterFunc() {
        String myString = "";
        Formatter fmt = new Formatter();

        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            fmt.format("%4d", i);
            myString = myString + fmt;
        }
        System.out.println(myString);
    }

    static void stringFunc() {
        String myString = "";
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
            myString = myString + i + " ";
        }
        System.out.println(myString);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        stringFunc();
        System.out.println("\n");
        formatterFunc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the constructors for `java.util.Formatter` take an `Appendable` as an argument. But per the [Java API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter()) the default constructor (which is what you are using) uses a `StringBuilder`. (`StringBuilder` implements `Appendable`)

> The destination of the formatted output is a StringBuilder ...

Thus, every time you call `fmt.format()` you are appending to the same `StringBuilder` each time.

Your choices of fix are:

1. Dispense with `String` concatenation, and use only the `Formatter`:

   ```
   static void formatterFunc() {
       try(Formatter fmt = new Formatter()) {  // Formatter should also be properly closed
           for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
               fmt.format("%4d", i);
           }
           System.out.println(fmt);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use a new `Formatter` each time

   ```
   static void formatterFunc() {
       String myString = "";
       for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
           myString = myString + new Formatter().format("%4d", i); // But needs closing strictly speaking
       }
       System.out.println(myString);
   }
   ```
3. Supply your own `Appendable`

   ```
   static void formatterFunc() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       try(Formatter fmt = new Formatter(sb)) {  // Formatter should be properly closed
           for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
               fmt.format("%4d", i);
           }
       }
       System.out.println(sb.toString()); // We can print this even after Formatter has been closed
   }
   ```